# I want to create a system in Javascript or JQuery where by I can capture the <a></a> link anchor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want capture all  on my website then, create a simple system where by, when users click on the link, it open the capture Link in another tap without requesting permission from browser then replace the former Tab with other link.

Let say I am on https://odap.biz and I want to click on the LOGIN link, The Javascript or JQuery must capture my LINK url then when I click on the LOGIN Button, it will open the capture link in another tab, without asking for permission popup, then the Tab I move from Will be replace with another link https://usuallyformal.com/ruxwbb1a72?key=ca706a44a54f2663cc4f2cfad4f51940.

i.e. If I am currently in TAB A in my browser, and my current Link  https://odap.biz and I am about clicking on a button that will go to https://odap.biz/login. When I click on the Button a new TAB B will be open with url https://odap.biz/login so the present TAB A with https://odap.biz will be replace with https://usuallyformal.com/ruxwbb1a72?key=ca706a44a54f2663cc4f2cfad4f51940.

This is what I did, But I will have to have ID for all links, and I don't want that, I want it to grap Link in all pages automatically. Also this code needs permission and I will like it to run under without user knowing.

```
<center><a role="button" id='mike' href="<?php echo "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/text" ?>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</a></center>
<script>
    let linkElement = document.getElementById("mike");
linkElement.addEventListener("click", openNew);

function openNew() {
    window.open("https://itinerarycarter.com/jyb4dx9x7f?key=7944c627b591f7b6eebb59ff66b0adcb", "_self");
    
    window.focus();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Then obviously edit the code to best suit your need. Mark correct if this resolved your issue.

```html
<center><a role="button" id='mike' href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</a></center>
<script>
    let linkElement = document.getElementById("mike");
    linkElement.addEventListener("click", openNew);

  function request (URL) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
      resolve(location.href = URL);
    });
  }

  async function openNew() {
    const response = await request('https://usuallyformal.com/ruxwbb1a72?key=ca706a44a54f2663cc4f2cfad4f51940');

    window.open("https://itinerarycarter.com/jyb4dx9x7f?key=7944c627b591f7b6eebb59ff66b0adcb", "_blank");

      window.focus();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is not working, Please read My request, you are given me another code

Comment: I've updated the code. The use of Async Await should do the trick.